# Is the following and isomorphism $H_0^1(\Omega) \to H^{-1}(\Omega)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

While working with differentiation with respect to the domain I stumbled upon the following question. Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^N$ be bounded, $\alpha \in L^\infty (\Omega)$ be non-negative and let 
$$   \varphi \in H_0^1(\Omega) \mapsto -\Delta \varphi + \alpha \varphi \in H^{-1}(\Omega)$$
be a linear application. I would like to show that this application is an isomorphism. I have no troubles as to proof that it is injective, but I can go no further.

I would wholeheartedly thank any suggestion.

Regards,
DG

Comment: Are you sure that this is injective? If $\alpha$ is an eigenvalue of the Laplacian you should run into trouble. It should work if $\alpha\geq 0$

Comment: I did say $\alpha$ non-negative.

I am fairly certain it holds. Since equality holds in $H^{-1}(\Omega)$ we must have 
$$0 = \int_{\Omega} ((-\Delta \varphi) \varphi + \alpha \varphi^2 ) = \int_{\Omega} (|\nabla \varphi|^2 + \alpha \varphi^2) \ge \int_{\Omega} |\nabla \varphi |^2$$
the latter being a norm on $H_0^1(\Omega)$ by Poincaré's inequality. Thus the application has kernel $\{0\}$.

Comment: I'm sorry, somehow i didn't recognize the non-negativity. I think one could also check several variants of Riesz representation theorem or Lax-Milgram's theorem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Apply [Browder–Minty theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browder%E2%80%93Minty_theorem).

Comment: I must thank you, Tomás. Your suggestion solved my problem straightforwardly. I leave the reference of the theorem for those interested: Renardy, Michael and Rogers, Robert C. (2004). An introduction to partial differential equations. Texts in Applied Mathematics 13 (Second edition ed.). New York: Springer-Verlag. p. 364. ISBN 0-387-00444-0 (Theorem 10.49)

Comment: You are welcome @D.G.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add a final remark. This can much more be proven with Lax-Milgram's Theorem. The above mentioned operator can be seen as a bilinear form.